# How to show line for zero value in barchart in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell me how to show a line for a zero value in barchart in extjs4.1? If the value is greater than zero, I need to display a bar. If it is zero, I need to show a line or marker.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar thread on sencha forums. Please take a look :

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?268339-How-to-show-line-for-zero-value-in-barchart-in-extjs4.1&p=984016#post984016